# sending and receiving byte array using rest template in service to service call java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, microservices

I want to send the message that i am receiving from a kafka topic to a different service using restTemplate.
The message could be of any type, that is why i want to convert the payload to byte array and send to the next service and expect next service will deserialize the byte array to the desired format.

I am facing challenges in two sections -

- when i am trying to send the byte array usning restTemplate what
  would be the content type should i set?
- I tried with octate-stream but when i am receiveng the byte array in
  the second service , it cannot convert back to an xml formatted
  string (that i am testing with)

Here is the example below -

**KafkaTopicListener.java**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test-topic", groupId = "group-id", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> cr,
            @Payload byte[] payload) {
        
        System.out.println("KafkaTopicListener.listen : payload ::"+payload.toString());
        
        String s = new String(payload);     
        System.out.println("KafkaTopicListener.listen : payload ::"+s); //getting proper string for an xml formatted in string that i posted on kafka
    
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
          
    
        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(payload, headers);
        
        restTemplate.postForLocation(nextSerivceURL, entity);
                 
    }
```

**NextServiceController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testByteArray", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void testByteArray(@RequestBody byte[] payload) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        

        //String s = new String(payload); 
    
        
        //System.out.println("NextServiceController.testByteArray::"+decoded.toString());
        String s = new String(payload); 
        System.out.println("NextServiceController.testByteArray String::"+s);
        

        // getting only a encoded string like NextserivceController.testByteArray //String::"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"

        
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug or print the received String in order to check what's the problem? why not sending it directly as String since it's an xml content by that you can avoid the encoding problem.